# May I update state using useRef hook instead of onChange event in React js?

Tags: reactjs, state, onchange, use-ref

While looking for the way to avoid rendering of a component after each change in input field I came across a suggestion to use useRef instead of onChange event for state update. It seems ok in simple components, but since I am a beginner  I do not know is this a good approach in more complex applications.  Shell I continue this way or I should stick back to onChange event?
I searched a lot to resolve this dilemma but was not able to find explicit answer.  Any suggestion in this regard will be more tan welcomed.

This is how it looks in a component:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AddData : React.FC= () => {

  const initialData = {
    firstValue: '',
    secondValue : ''            
  }
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);  
  const firstInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const secondInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);          

  const handleSetData = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {    
    if(firstInputRef.current !== null && secondInputRef.current !== null) {      
      setData({
        ...data, 
            firstValue: firstInputRef.current.value,
            secondValue: secondInputRef.current.value                           
      })      
    }    
  }

  const handleFormSubmit = async (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
    const {firstValue, secondValue} = data;
    if(firstValue !== '' && secondValue !== '') {         
      await axios.post('url', {
        ...data    
      }).then((response) => {  });      
    }
  }   

  return(
    <>      
      <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>        
        <input type='text' ref={firstInputRef} />
        <input type='text' ref={secondInputRef} />            
        <button onClick={handleSetData}> Submit Form </button>
      </form >
    </>
  );
}
export default AddData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you use are called uncontrolled form elements, and are alternative to controlled elements on official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). In most cases React recommends to use controlled ones, but I suppose it is no harm to use the uncontrolled ones too if you wish.

> In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement
> forms. In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React
> component. The alternative is uncontrolled components, where form data
> is handled by the DOM itself.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Should I at all think too much about rerendering while working with forms?

Comment: @ahmed.zubaca You are welcome, you can accept answer if it helped you. You can think about rerendering if you have large forms or notice performance problems, in that case I suggest you look into `React.memo` and `useCallback` functions, you can create custom form components which don't rerender if their input didn't change for example.

Comment: You helped me a lot. My understanding now is that this kind of uncontrolled form, basicaly, is not wrong. Thanks, one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
const firstInputRef = useRef (null);
```

instead

```
 const firstInputRef = useRef <HTMLFormElement> (null);
```

Recommended by the react team
useRef is **recomandary use when you reading value**, recomandary by team React.
useRef will give you the same ref object on every render ,

Keep in mind that **useRef doesn't notify you when its content changes**, you want to use a function useCallback